# How do I create a card grid view HTML, CSS and Flask

Tags: html, css, flask, gridview

I am using the code in my index.html file.

```
    {% for post in blog_posts.items %}

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card" >

        <div class="card-body">

          <h2><a class="card-title" href="  {{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_post', blog_post_id=post.id) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <a href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}">Written By: {{ post.author.username }}</a>
          <p>Published on: {{ post.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</p>
          <p class="card-text">{{ post.text[:100] }}...</p>
          <a href="{{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_post', blog_post_id=post.id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read Blog Post</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   {% endfor %}
```

My understanding from bootstrap is that it would create a 6 column grid, however it is just stacking one card below the next.  I am sure it is something I am missing.  Thank you for your help.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use a card deck or card group to achieve this:

I'd lose this div:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
```

Then put the `for` loop within a `card-group` div:

```
<div class='card-group'>
    {% for post in blog_posts.items %}
      <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-body">
          ...
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If you want some spacing between the cards, you can change the class of the outer div to `card-deck`.

See the [Card docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#) for more options.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps me understand it.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`.col-sm-6{ display: flex }` add this css property to the parent that contains all cards.

alternatively you can use floats `.col-sm-6 > .card{ float: left}`

Comment: i find bootstrap hard because you have to follow a particular syntax and your styling is specified by bootstraps styling... learn css  and use it over bootstrap